# How Mount a datastore on linux in python

Tags: linux, scripting, python, programming, automake

I need to mount xyz/pqr/ datastore on my linux mychine for in my python script.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily run Linux commands from Python with `subprocess` library.

So check [this site](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).